# Haskelll Data Constructor not in scope

Tags: haskell

So I have Base.hs that contains

```
data RoseTree a = Node a [RoseTree a] | Nil
  deriving(Show)
```

In Applicative.hs I have,

```
import Base
instance Applicative RoseTree where
   pure :: a -> RoseTree a
   pure = RoseTree  

   (<*>) :: RoseTree (a -> b) -> RoseTree a -> RoseTree b
   (<*>) _ Nil = Nil
   (<*>) Nil _ = Nil
   (<*>) (Node f tree) (Node x [subtrees]) = Node (f x) (nestedMap f [subtrees] ++ nestedApply tree subtrees)
```

I got this error,

```
Data constructor not in scope: RoseTree :: a -> RoseTree a
    |
141 |   pure = RoseTree
    |          ^^^^^^^^
Failed, two modules loaded.
```

I expect to have these outputs,

```
>>> (Node (+1) []) <*> (Node 7 [Node 1 [], Node 2 [], Node 3 [Node 4 []]])
Node 8 [Node 2 [],Node 3 [],Node 4 [Node 5 []]]

>>> (Node (+1) [Node (*2) []]) <*> (Node 5 [Node 2 [], Node 8 [Node 1 []]])
Node 6 [Node 3 [],Node 9 [Node 2 []],Node 10 [Node 4 [],Node 16 [Node 2 []]]]
```

Comment: The `[subtrees]` pattern will only match nodes with *one* child. Likely that is not what you want?

Answer (score 4):

`RoseTree` is the name of the *type* constructor, not the *data* constructor. The *data* constructors are `Node` and `Nil`. So likely your `pure` should be a `Node … []`:

```
instance Applicative RoseTree where
    pure x = Node x []
```

or in a point-free style:

```
instance Applicative RoseTree where
    pure = (`Node` [])
```

Note that the:

```
(<*>) (Node f tree) (Node x [subtrees]) = …
```

pattern will only "*fire*" in case the second `RoseTree` has *exactly* one subtree (so it will not match if the node has zero, or two or more subtrees). Likely you thus should redefine this. It is however not entirely clear what the semantics should be when you apply use a `Node` at the right operand with no subtrees, or multiple ones.

Likely you want to implement something like:

```
instance Applicative RoseTree where
    pure x = Node x []
    (<*>) Nil _ = Nil
    (<*>) _ Nil = Nil
    (<*>) (Node f tree) r@(Node x subtrees) = Node (f x) (map (fmap f) subtrees ++ map (<*> r) tree)
```

But I'm not sure this satisfies the laws for an `Applicative` instance, at first sight I don't think this does.

Comment: How would you suggest a solution for the outputs i added above?

Comment: @MichaelShane: the main problem is that you first need to define yourself *how* the semantics of your `app` should work. This should also satisfy the `Applicative` constraints (and in harmony with the `Functor` instance).